# Does it matter which pixel format type we choose for AVCaptureSession to run CoreML model using Vision?

Tags: ios, coreml, apple-vision, cvpixelbuffer

I am using Apple's sample app Breakfast finder which does detection and it use pixel format type in biplanar yuv format. I changed it to ARGB and its running on my own model trained on Turi create. Now i have no idea changing the pixel format type have any effects on performing vision requests on buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Vision and/or Core ML will automatically convert the CVPixelBuffer to the pixel format that your model expects, so you shouldn't have to worry about it.

(If you use Core ML directly, I believe the pixel format must be BGRA or ARGB, but Vision seems to be more flexible.)

See the CheckInputImage sample app from my [Core ML Survival Guide repo](https://github.com/hollance/coreml-survival-guide), which lets you double-check that the image seen by Vision / Core ML is really what you expected.